# Data entry in database on clicking 'YES' in dialogbox

Tags: java, dialog

Here's the thing: I'm doing some entry into a database. After the row is inserted, I want to show a dialog box saying "Data entered in database. Do you want to export it to Excel?"

I know the code for connection to Excel. The problem is this that I want to click on the "Yes" button in the dialog box to enter data into Excel.

How do I add action performed on dialog box?
I tried this [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just something like this?

```
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
             "Would you like to export to Excel?",
             "Export", 
             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
     //Excel Logic
}
else {
     //Not Excel Logic
}
```